# Function constructor in Crockford's pseudoclassical inheritance section

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

What does he mean by this:

> "When a function object is created, the Function constructor that
>   produces the function object runs some code like this:
>
> `this.prototype = {constructor: this};`
>
> The new function object is given a prototype property whose value is
>   an object containing a constructor property whose value is the new
>   function object"

Explanation with an example would be great.

Comment: Try to create a function and then inspect its `.prototype` property.

Comment: I'm not sure what is unclear about "*When a function object is created, it is given a prototype property whose value is an object containing a constructor property whose value is the new function object*". What part of that don't you understand?

Comment: doug makes it sound more complicated than it is by being overly precise...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For example, when you define this constructor:

```
function MyConstructor() {
   // ...
}
```

It automatically receives a `prototype` property. Its value is an object with a `constructor` property, which points back to the constructor:

```
MyConstructor.prototype; // some object
MyConstructor.prototype.constructor; // MyConstructor
```

This is specified in [Creating Function Objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2):

> 1. Create a new native ECMAScript object and let *F* be that object.
>
> 16. Let *proto* be the result of creating a new object as would be constructed by the expression `new Object()` where `Object` is the
>       standard built-in constructor with that name.
> 17. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *proto* with arguments `"constructor"`, [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]: *F*, {
>       [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **false**, [[Configurable]]:
>       **true**}, and **false**.
> 18. Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *F* with arguments `"prototype"`, [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10)
>       {[[Value]]: *proto*, { [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]:
>       **false**, [[Configurable]]: **false**}, and **false**.

Then, instances of the constructor will inherit from its `prototype` object:

```
var myInstance = new MyConstructor();
Object.getPrototypeOf(myInstance); // MyConstructor.prototype
```

In case you want to know the constructor used to create the instance, you can use the `constructor` property, which hopefully will be inherited:

```
myInstance.constructor; // MyConstructor
```

Comment: +1                                                                                               for citing the spec - in the hope that it doesn't confuse the OP even more